# Constrain variables when using NSolve

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, assumptions

I'm working with a system of n-equations and `Nsolve` takes too long to get the results. I'm trying to speed things up by adding a restriction to the solutions, but I'm not sure how to set the restriction to all the variables in the list.

```
EQ = {eq1, eq2, ..., eqN}
X = {var1, var2, ..., varN}
NSolve[EQ, X]
```

How can I add that:

```
var1,`va2, ..., varN ∈ Interval[{0,a}]
```

without going 1 by 1 since the size n may change?

#### Edit

So here is the actual code for n=4:

```
EQ =
 {5. (1/4 (Subsuperscript[respr, 1, 2]/2 - Subscript[respr, 1] + 1/2) +
      1/4 (Subsuperscript[respr, 2, 2]/2 - Subscript[respr, 2] + 1/2) +
      1/4 (Subsuperscript[respr, 3, 2]/2 - Subscript[respr, 3] + 1/2) +
      1/4 (Subsuperscript[respr, 4, 2]/2 - Subscript[respr, 4] + 
         1/2)) -
   Subscript[respr, 1] + (1 - Subscript[respr, 1]) 
    ((1 - Subscript[respr, 1])/
       (4 (1/4 (1 - Subscript[respr, 2]) + 
            1/4 (1 - Subscript[respr, 3]) +
            1/4 (1 - Subscript[respr, 4])) + 0.8) + 1) + 0.5,
  5. (1/4 (Subsuperscript[respr, 1, 2]/2 - Subscript[respr, 1] + 1/2) +
      1/4 (Subsuperscript[respr, 2, 2]/2 - Subscript[respr, 2] + 1/2) +
      1/4 (Subsuperscript[respr, 3, 2]/2 - Subscript[respr, 3] + 1/2) +
      1/4 (Subsuperscript[respr, 4, 2]/2 - Subscript[respr, 4] + 
         1/2)) -
   Subscript[respr, 2] + (1 - Subscript[respr, 2]) 
    ((1 - Subscript[respr, 2])/
       (4 (1/4 (1 - Subscript[respr, 1]) + 
            1/4 (1 - Subscript[respr, 3]) +
            1/4 (1 - Subscript[respr, 4])) + 0.8) + 1) + 0.5,
  5. (1/4 (Subsuperscript[respr, 1, 2]/2 - Subscript[respr, 1] + 
         1/2) + \1/4 (Subsuperscript[respr, 2, 2]/2 - 
         Subscript[respr, 2] + 1/2) +
      1/4 (Subsuperscript[respr, 3, 2]/2 - Subscript[respr, 3] + 1/2) +
      1/4 (Subsuperscript[respr, 4, 2]/2 - Subscript[respr, 4] + 
         1/2)) -
   Subscript[respr, 3] + (1 - Subscript[respr, 3]) 
    ((1 - Subscript[respr, 3])/
       (4 (1/4 (1 - Subscript[respr, 1]) + 
            1/4 (1 - Subscript[respr, 2]) +
            1/4 (1 - Subscript[respr, 4])) + 0.8) + 1) + 0.5,
  5. (1/4 (Subsuperscript[respr, 1, 2]/2 - Subscript[respr, 1] + 1/2) +
      1/4 (Subsuperscript[respr, 2, 2]/2 - Subscript[respr, 2] + 1/2) +
      1/4 (Subsuperscript[respr, 3, 2]/2 - Subscript[respr, 3] + 1/2) +
      1/4 (Subsuperscript[respr, 4, 2]/2 - Subscript[respr, 4] + 
         1/2)) +
   ((1 - Subscript[respr, 4])/
       (4 (1/4 (1 - Subscript[respr, 1]) + 
            1/4 (1 - Subscript[respr, 2]) +
            1/4 (1 - Subscript[respr, 3])) + 0.8) + 1) 
    (1 - Subscript[respr, 4]) - Subscript[respr, 4] + 0.5}

X =
  {Subscript[respr, 1], Subscript[respr, 2], 
   Subscript[respr, 3], Subscript[respr, 4]}
```

Im solving this by:

```
NSolve[EQ, X]
```

I would like to set a restriction to all the variables `Subscript[respr,1]`. However I cannot use `&& Subscript[respr,1] \[Element] Interval[{0,1}]`, 1 by 1 since n may be 10 or 100 in each run.

Comment: Try to use `FindRoot`

Comment: There is no such thing like `Nsolve`; there is [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html), though.

Comment: Mmm it doesnt work, I get this error: Nsolve: eq1 should be a length 1 list of real-valued quantities.

Comment: Note that the variable `Subsuperscript[respr, 1, 2]` has no relation to the variable `Subscript[respr, 1]`.  I suppose you meant to square the variable `Subscript[respr, 1]`?  That's done with ``Subscript[respr, 1]^2` (or `Power[]`).  [The standard advice is to avoid `Subscript`, except for output formatting -- see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/4999.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
NSolve[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, x^2 - y^2 + y^3 == 1/2, 
  AllTrue[{x, y}, {#} ∈ Interval[{0, 2}] &]}]
(*  {{x -> 0.802265, y -> 0.596968}}  *)
```

I don't really think that will speed things up, though, but that might depend on the actual system of equations.

---

*Update: Response to updated question*

```
Block[{Subsuperscript = Subscript[#1, #2]^#3 &}, 
 NSolve[EQ~Append~AllTrue[X, {#} \[Element] Interval[{0, 1}] &], X]
 ]
(*
{{Subscript[respr, 1] -> 0.808928, Subscript[respr, 2] -> 0.808928, 
  Subscript[respr, 3] -> 0.808928, Subscript[respr, 4] -> 0.808928}}
*)
```

I'm going out on a limb and guessing that `Subsuperscript[respr, 1, 2]`, etc. are meant to represent `Subscript[respr, 1]^2` and so forth.

Comment: Mmm couldn't add the AllTrue to the NSolve with my current structure of EQ and X

Comment: @Rodrigo I guess you need to explain why in the question.  (E.g. add [a minimal working example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).)

Comment: well I thought I had that, I have a list of equations (EQ), and a list of variables (X) and the syntax that I'm using. I'll work into something more detailed, then.

Comment: @Rodrigo "Working" means it works when a user pastes it into *Mathemetica* -- thanks for the edit.